# Unable to retrieve Facebook user properties

Tags: django, facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

I am following [this tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas). I am trying to retrieve the user properties; first_name but I got `None` as the result.

I am able to retrieve some user properties like name, picture and email though.

*main.py*

```
 class User(db.Model):
        user_id = db.StringProperty(required=True)
        access_token = db.StringProperty(required=True)
        name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
        first_name = db.StringProperty()
        picture = db.StringProperty(required=True)
        email = db.StringProperty()
        friends = db.StringListProperty()
        dirty = db.BooleanProperty()

        def refresh_data(self):
            """Refresh this user's data using the Facebook Graph API"""
            me = Facebook().api(u'/me',
                {u'fields': u'picture,friends', u'access_token': self.access_token})
            self.dirty = False
            self.name = me[u'name']
            self.first_name = me[u'first_name']
            self.email = me.get(u'email')
            self.picture = me[u'picture']
            self.friends = [user[u'id'] for user in me[u'friends'][u'data']]
            return self.put()
```

...

```
def init_facebook(self):
    """Sets up the request specific Facebook and User instance"""
    facebook = Facebook()
    user = None

    # initial facebook request comes in as a POST with a signed_request
    if u'signed_request' in self.request.POST:
        facebook.load_signed_request(self.request.get('signed_request'))
        # we reset the method to GET because a request from facebook with a
        # signed_request uses POST for security reasons, despite it
        # actually being a GET. in webapp causes loss of request.POST data.
        self.request.method = u'GET'
        self.set_cookie(
            'u', facebook.user_cookie, datetime.timedelta(minutes=1440))
    elif 'u' in self.request.cookies:
        facebook.load_signed_request(self.request.cookies.get('u'))

    # try to load or create a user object
    if facebook.user_id:
        user = User.get_by_key_name(facebook.user_id)
        if user:
            # update stored access_token
            if facebook.access_token and \
                    facebook.access_token != user.access_token:
                user.access_token = facebook.access_token
                user.put()
            # refresh data if we failed in doing so after a realtime ping
            if user.dirty:
                user.refresh_data()
            # restore stored access_token if necessary
            if not facebook.access_token:
                facebook.access_token = user.access_token

        if not user and facebook.access_token:
            me = facebook.api(u'/me', {u'fields': u'picture,friends'})
            user = User(key_name=facebook.user_id,
                user_id=facebook.user_id,
                access_token=facebook.access_token,
                name=me[u'name'],
                first_name=facebook.first_name,
                email=me.get(u'email'),  # optional
                picture=me[u'picture'],
                friends=[user[u'id'] for user in me[u'friends'][u'data']])
            user.put()

    self.facebook = facebook
    self.user = user
```

*runs.html*

```
<strong>first name:</strong>  
    {{ logged_in_user.first_name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is becouse you are asking only by "picture" and "friends"

```
me = Facebook().api(u'/me',
                {u'fields': u'picture,friends', u'access_token': self.access_token})
```

try only with access_token

```
me = Facebook().api(u'/me',
                {u'access_token': self.access_token})
```